# Get data for Related List

Tags: visual-workflow, related-list

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to solve this so I thought maybe you could help.

I need to pull some data from my Product object to a new object in a Related List.

Basically I need to: everytime I create a New Quote for an Opportunity, I need this Related List here to pull the Name and Price of all my Products related to the Opportunity.

[image]

***EDIT***: Since I'm still trying to solve this one, I'm gonna bring out here how I think this can be solved.

Through a Flow:

- Basically I need to create a Triggered-Flow that will run when creating the Quote.;
- Get the Product data that I will have from the Opportunity;
- Create the variables there to store what I need - Product Name & Price (how?)...

Hope you can help, cheers <3

Comment: Have you tried using formula fields to pull in this information?  It's not the only step (you'd need to modify the related lists fields from your Opportunity page layout(s)), but still probably the simplest and most effective way to bring related data into a related list.

Comment: Hey @DerekF thanks for the answer man, appreciate it. I'll try that now, but thinking about it...
I need the related list to be automated, so when I create a Quote, the Product data goes directly to my 'Quote Line Item'.
Is this the right direction?

Comment: Sorry if maybe I'm missing some basic Salesforce knowledge, I'm still a beginner.
I'm just stucked here because I don't know how to automate a 'create a record'. - basically I need a related list to create X records based on how many Products I have in my Opportunity.